# In node.js, how do I get Request Unit Charges from call to DocumentClient.queryDocuments()?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, request-unit

I'm using the [queryDocuments() method from the node.js client](http://dl.windowsazure.com/documentDB/nodedocs/DocumentClient.html#queryDocuments) for the first time. I've previously used readDocument(), executeStoredProcedure(), replaceStoredProcedure(), etc. and all of those return a header object that allows you to inspect the 'x-ms-request-charge' header to discern the request unit charge for the operation. However, when using the queryDocuments() or readDocuments() methods, it returns an QueryIterator and I don't see a way to inspect it to see the RUs for the operation.

I suspect that the reason for this is that it's not one operation. It's a series of operations and you didn't implement a way to aggregate the total RUs for the entire thing. I'm willing to hit the REST API directly to get this myself, but I wanted to ask if there was a way to get it with the current library before I went through the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect response headers (e.g. `x-ms-request-charge`) by inspecting the third input parameter in the `callback` for `queryIterator.executeNext()`.

For example, here is a code sample that uses the response header (`x-ms-retry-after-ms`) to implement retry logic on throttles (error 429).

```
var queryIterator = documentClient.queryDocuments(collection._self, query);
executeNextWithRetry(yourCallback);

function executeNextWithRetry(callback) {
    queryIterator.executeNext(function(err, results, responseHeaders) {
        if(err && err.code === 429 && responseHeaders['x-ms-retry-after-ms']) {

            console.log("Retrying after " + responseHeaders['x-ms-retry-after-ms']);

            setTimeout(function() {
                executeNextWithRetry(callback);
            }, responseHeaders['x-ms-retry-after-ms']);

        } else {
            callback(err, results, responseHeaders);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I submitted a pull request to update the docs for executeNext(). It currently says, "takes two parameters error, resourcesList". I noticed that my last doc fix pull request never got merged so I added it to this latest.